# notification led doesn't work

Tags: android, android-notifications

```
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
notification.ledARGB = Color.BLUE;
notification.ledOnMS = 1000; 
notification.ledOffMS = 1000;

notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
notificationManager.notify(notifyId, notification);
```

the code work in an app, but doesn't work in another. The led doesn't flash.
Any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: what is the version of software you use ? Have you got set the priority of the led notification ? and try to increase ledOnMS to 3000

Comment: set the priority?  what does that means?

Comment: like this : `notification.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for my careless, the reaseon is this one line code:

```
notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
```

it means that all the setting, include Light, Sound, Vibration, all follow the system setting.

because of this, this code doesn't work.

```
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
notification.ledARGB = Color.BLUE;
notification.ledOnMS = 1000; 
notification.ledOffMS = 1000;
```